# Can't connect to mongodb replica set with Mongodb Compass

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-compass

I am trying to install MongoDB replica set using Docker with a docker-compose.yml file as follows:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - cluster
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile.txt:/opt/keyFile.txt
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: user123
      MONGO_INITDB_AUTH_SOURCE: admin
    command: mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyFile.txt --replSet myReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo1
  mongo2:
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    networks:
      - cluster
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile.txt:/opt/keyFile.txt
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: user123
      MONGO_INITDB_AUTH_SOURCE: admin
    command: mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyFile.txt --replSet myReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo2
  mongo3:
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    networks:
      - cluster
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile.txt:/opt/keyFile.txt
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: user123
      MONGO_INITDB_AUTH_SOURCE: admin
    command: mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyFile.txt --replSet myReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,mongo3

networks:
  cluster:
```

I am running the `docker-compose up` command to start all the services. In my terminal, I am seeing logs like this:

```
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:28.460+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23400}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:28.622+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23400}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:28.654+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":18800}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:47.468+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":19000}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:51.868+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23600}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:52.033+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23600}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:53.714+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:46:53.714+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20711,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Failed to reap transaction table","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:06.485+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":19200}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:15.479+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23800}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:15.659+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":23800}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:25.701+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":19400}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:39.305+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24000}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:39.463+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24000}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:47:45.122+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":19600}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:03.331+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24200}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:03.486+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24200}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:04.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":19800}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:24.545+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":20000}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:27.536+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24400}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:27.696+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24400}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:44.547+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":20200}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:50.322+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:50.322+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20711,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Failed to reap transaction table","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:50.325+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:50.325+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20711,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Failed to reap transaction table","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:51.957+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24600}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:48:52.100+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24600}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:04.772+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":20400}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:16.580+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24800}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:16.727+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24800}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:25.181+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":20600}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:41.400+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":25000}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:41.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":25000}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:49:45.800+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":20800}}
mongo3  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:50:06.403+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":25200}}
mongo2  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:50:06.574+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":25200}}
mongo1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-04-13T12:50:06.608+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":21000}}
```

**Note**: The `keyFile.txt` file is in the same folder as the `docker-compose.yml` file

Can anyone help me please? I have been stuck with this issue for two days.

Comment: Looks like the replica set is not initiated. But I have no clue about docker, thus I cannot help you.

Comment: hmm.. If the replica set is configured but not initialized properly, is it still possible to connect to one of the databases? If so, then the issue might not be with the replica set itself.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to a single instance and initiate manually.

Comment: Huh, maybe I will wait for the answer until someone can provide some clarity. Thank you very much.